# react-native-image-picker: NativeModule.ImagePickerManager is null

Tags: react-native, react-native-image-picker, react-native-picker-select

I am trying to use react native image picker in visual studio code.

Try steps to link image picker "npx react-native link react-native-image-picker" and its linking successfully but when I run my project I got below error :

```
 Error: react-native-image-picker: NativeModule.ImagePickerManager is null. To fix this issue try these steps:
    • Run `react-native link react-native-image-picker` in the project root.
    • Rebuild and re-run the app.
```

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs mainly in two reasons :

1. The module is not installed properly .
2. Update to the latest version of image picker .

and there are some solution given in below link -
https://github.com/react-native-image-picker/react-native-image-picker/issues/1137